# Refresh Excel Data Connections one at a time for logging purposes

Tags: excel, vba

We have a large workbook with about 12 data connections. Each morning, a macro runs which does a refresh all, among other things.

To make a long story short, I want to make each data connection refresh separately, and to log the time it refreshes (Either start or end).

The logging part is no big deal, but I am struggling to find a way to get each connection to refresh independently. Or, in other words, a way to make a single data connection refresh.

Comment: A loop, or calling `.ReFresh` on each connection.

Comment: I am struggling with the syntax for this.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: I have to ask the dumb question, but did you read the linked thread already?